# Django and get_absolute_url

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have simple "post" model which represents an entry for my blog:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('title', max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField('slug', unique_for_date='creation_time')
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField('creation time', auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField('content')

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('devblog_post_url', (), {
            'year': self.creation_time.year,
            'month': self.creation_time.month,
            'day': self.creation_time.day,
            'slug': self.slug})
```

At the index of my blog, I want to paginate these Posts with this view:

```
def index_view(request):
    published_posts = Post.objects.all()    
    paginator = Paginator(published_posts, 10)
    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
    except ValueError:
        page = 1
    try:
        post_list = paginator.page(page)
    except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        post_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render_to_response('devblog_index.html', {"post_list": post_list})
```

And now here is the problem, I get blank urls once I call the get_absolute_url method for a post with `devblog_index.html` template:

```
{% for post in post_list.object_list %}
    <a href="/{{ post.get_absolute_url }}/">{{ post.title }}</a><br />
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is my urls.py for my application:

from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',
        view='devblog.views.index_view',
        name='devblog_index'
    ),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{1,2)/(?P<day>\d{1,2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        view='devblog.views.post_view', name='devblog_post_url'
    )
)
```

at the main urls.py, I simple include it as `(r'^blog/', include('devblog.urls'))`

Where can be the problem for this blank string url ?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `(?P<month>\w{1,2)` to `(?P<month>\d{1,2})`.